# initialize epoll which is static in c++

Tags: c++

I have an epoll fd as a static member in classA. My intention is to keep it sole for my application hence kept it static. All the objects of classA listens on same epoll fd.

I know static members should be defined outside to memory be allocated, I wrote like this:

```
   int classA::_epoll_fd = epoll_create(64);
```

My question, how shall I ensure epoll created successfully. Do I need to check in the constructor of classA ? but this will be checked for all the objects unnecessarily.

Anyone please help. Please let me know if design level changes needed ?

Comment: write a new function (say initEpollFd) to create and check for error.

Answer (score 1):

The `classA::_epoll_fd` is unique and its initialization is called in the beginning of the execution. The `epoll_create(64)` will be called before `main` function. If `epoll_create(64)` runs always successfully you do not have to check anything.